# quit button not working properly with electron and render script

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm trying to make a quit button for my Electron app, but every time I press it it does nothing.

I currently have the following set up in my files:

main.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Menu} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path')

...

ipcMain.on('quitApp', () => {
    app.quit();
})
```

render.js:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

const closeApp = document.getElementById('closeApp');
closeApp.addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('quitApp');
});
```

index.html:

```
    <body>
        <div class="menu">    
        ...
            <button id="closeApp">Quit</button>
            <script src="./scripts/render.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First edit the first line of render.js to

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
```

Besides, Check  that you put in the `BrowserWindow.webPreferences` `nodeINtegration:true` and `contextIsolation : false`.

Comment: ah great, I was missing the ```contextIsolation: false``` part in webPreferences. works now! thanks